# GWT - google vizualization tools - scheduling a chart refresh

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I am building an application that display semi-real time data (refresh every minute) using google visualization tools in gwt. Since I am very new to GWT I was following this guide:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted

I got this code at the moment:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a callback to be called when the visualization API has been loaded.
    Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Panel panel = RootPanel.get("graph_box");
            // Create a chart visualization.
            AnnotatedTimeLine graph = new AnnotatedTimeLine(createTable(), createOptions(), "1000px", "500px");

            graph.addStyleName("timeLine");
            panel.add(graph);
        }
    };

    // Load the visualization api, passing the onLoadCallback to be called when loading is done.
    VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, AnnotatedTimeLine.PACKAGE);

    Timer timeoutTimer = new Timer() {
        public void run() {
            Window.alert("Reloaded chart.");
        }
    };
    timeoutTimer.scheduleRepeating(1000 * 3);
}
```

and I am not clear how to call the draw() function of AnnotatedTimeLine (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline) inside my scheduler, so that it redraws itself, without reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare `AnnotatedTimeLine graph` outside the method (as a field of your class) so that you can access it from outside (in the Timer.run() method)?